# Style an element only when there is no sibling element

Tags: html, css, sass

Basically I want to style a p tag when it is not present inside another div.

For example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p>I want to style here</p>
        <div class="secondClass">
            <p>I don't want to style here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following but no luck

```
.container > :not(.secondClass) + p {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: `.container > .row > p` would that do it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe that should do the job, but I went with @mohamed-drira answer as it will work even if row is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tou can change the style like this :

```
div > :not(.secondClass) > p {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this, depending on context. See code below:

```css
.container .row > p {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p>I want to style here</p>
        <div class="secondClass">
            <p>I don't want to style here</p>
        </div>
        <p>I want to style here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

,